# What is this "hole" in the A350 fuselage?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a350, feature-identification

As [usual](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36418/why-does-this-regional-jet-have-its-air-brakes-wide-open-before-touchdown), I was looking at pictures of planes flying around me. And then I noticed a weird hole in this Singapore Airlines A350 fuselage:

[image: The A350 hole]
[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Singapore-Airlines/Airbus-A350-941/4288423/L?qsp=eJwtjcEKwjAQRH9F9tyDUvTQW/0BBf2BJRlqsDZhd0FD6b%2B7Bm%2BPN8PMSiEvho/dawENpGAJD%2BqosPBLaVjpifrOEp1p7I/7bndLy8QlC7ymWexcPYpsGENAMcS/v0iE/CJoaIuTPxwcINfG1J/cx6Rl5rYB4zTTtn0B3uExaA%3D%3D)

Registration number of this plane is 9V-SMD. According to the angle we look at the plane, the hole is more or less visible:

[image: Another less visible hole]
[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Singapore-Airlines/Airbus-A350-941/4317553/L?qsp=eJwtjcEKwjAQRP9lz3oQQbC3ildRULwvm6EGYhM2W7CU/rtr8Da8ecwsJHk0fOwxF1BHFazyog0VVn5X6hZSDLGassU89mITJ/eOz%2B39cnavZrXT7CSwoRdBMYQ/v2qA/ipUaZODX%2Bw8QG8t0/7gPMRaErcNGMdE6/oFUKEyOA%3D%3D)

What is this hole, and what is its purpose?

Comment: Different plane, same thing though: [What exactly is this opening in the belly of a Boeing 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16566/what-exactly-is-this-opening-in-the-belly-of-a-boeing-737?noredirect=1&lq=1)